# How to disable scroll splash in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a container with a column inside it and its wrapped with a SingleChildScrollView widget.
I want to disable this scroll splash animation that comes when we reach the end of the scroll view.
This is what my widget tree looks like for this one.

```
Container - with rounded border
|
SingleChildScrollView
|
Column
|
Some widgets in children
```

[image: Scroll splash]
Because this comes over the rounded border of the container I want to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Apoorv, google has many solutions to this question, please check [this page](https://learnfluttertutorial.blogspot.com/2020/10/how-to-remove-scroll-glowsplash-in.html) for a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: MyBehavior(),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  home: new MyHomePage(),
);
```

and define custom scroll behavior like this

```
class MyBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    return child;
  }
}
```